# Zend doesn't load pdo_dblib

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdo

I'm trying to connect a Zend application (version 1.11.11) to an mssql server via pdo_dblib (using PHP version 7.0.22). I know that my PHP installation has pdo_dblib since running `print(extension_loaded('pdo_dblib'));` in the terminal returns `1`. In the .ini file I have:

```
resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mssql"
resources.db.params.pdoType = "pdo_dblib"
```

When I run the application with a debugger, the value of the statement `$a = extension_loaded('pdo_dblib');` is `false`.

As a result of this `PDO::getAvailableDrivers()` doesn't contain pdo_dblib (of course), which causes the application to throw an exception.

Does anyone know why this problem occurs, and how to fix it?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php did you enable the extension? On Linux boxes it would be something like `php_pdo_mssql.so`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is not Zend, but in a subtle detail of your tests:

- running `print(extension_loaded('pdo_dblib'));` **in the terminal** returns `1`
- when I run **the application** with a debugger, the value of the statement `$a = extension_loaded('pdo_dblib');` is `false`

PHP on the terminal is not guaranteed to have the same configuration, or even be the same version, as PHP on the web server of the same machine.

You will need to look into your hosting setup to find out how to enable the extension in the `php.ini` (or equivalent) in the web server's copy of PHP. The output of `phpinfo()` *run in your application, not the terminal*, may help.